# NLog filter to change Error to Warning

Tags: nlog

I currently have the following filters

```xml
<logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="dbLog">
  <filters>
    <when condition="contains('${message}', 'failed AntiXss')" action="Ignore" />
    <when condition="contains('${message}', 'Cannot create duplicate candidate')" action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

But instead of ignoring the errors, I need to log then as warnings.  Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunate not without programming/tricks.

The level is set with the log call and shouldn't be changes by targets.

A trick is to duplicate the target and write as "warning" in these cases.

e.g.

```xml
<target name="file"      xsi:type="File" layout="${level}|${message}"/>
<target name="file-warn" xsi:type="File" layout="WARN|{message}"/>
```

Comment: And then have filters in each of those ... GOT IT.